# Adobe AIR iOS Compiling with ANEs

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, ane

I'm impliment the Game Center ANE provided by Adobe to my AIR game for iOS developed in Adobe Flash CC 2015. 
I downloaded the latest ANE, which should be 64bit, but when I try to compile the file, or even export movie (Ctrl + Enter), I get this error:

```
Test Movie terminated.
The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Requested extension com.adobe.ane.gameCenter is not supported for Windows-x86.
```

When I tried using the "gameCenter.ane"-file included in the Gaming SDK by Adobe, I got an error saying:

```
META-INF/ANE/iPhone-ARM/libgameCenter.a are required to have universal iOS libraries. Please contact the ANE developer(s) to get the same.
```

I was able to export movie (Ctrl + Enter) with the original included gameCenter.ane file (from Gaming SDK), but not while using the 64bit.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan, got any useful info to add for a faster answer? I don't do ANEs but hope someone can help. Surely `is not supported for Windows-x86`(32-bit) might be the issue when used with a 64-bit ANE? What Flash version are you using? According to this **[link](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/animate/versions.html)** only Animate [Flash] **CC** version has _"iOS 64-bit support"_ and _"64-bit architecture"_ but those features are not available to older Flash **CS** versions...